# How to prevent Pagespeed from caching images from remote server?

Tags: php, apache, pagespeed

I have enabled Pagespeed (Apache's module) on my website http://frendsdom.com.

1) There are some images that are loaded from a different host. The real URL of a remote image would be like this- ***cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w500/o1nFdxKfPE9EFP6lSweEn2mx1Oi.jpg***

2) But Pagespeed converts that URL into something like this - ***cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w500/250x300xo1nFdxKfPE9EFP6lSweEn2mx1Oi.jpg.pagespeed.ic.pVxt1auT2O.jpg***

Consequently image doesn't load into browser as no such URL (2) exists. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need ModPagespeedDisallow [1].

I find it a little worrying though, that mod_pagespeed is trying to optimize cf2.imgobject.com 
when the html is being served from frendsdom.com. mod_pagespeed doesn't allow optimisation of resources hosted on other domains out of the box for security reasons, so you need to check your configuration for that. Is there a faulty ModPagespeedAllow line in there?

[1] https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/restricting_urls